# how to test wcf rest services in vs "unit test project"?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, rest, unit-testing

I've created a new solution with WCF REST services.  Now I need to unit test the services.  For example, here's a REST service url:

cars/{id}

The GET method should return a car object with the id provided in the querystring.  How can I configure through a VS unit test project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, create a self-hosted unit test, i.e.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Before_Each_Test()
{
   var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CarService));
   // Override with local endpoint, i.e. a TCP connection, local IP etc

   host.Open();
}
```

Then dont forget to shut down the host in TestCleanup, of course.

Comment: Thanks Pedro.  I can set up the host in [TestInitialize] but now I'm trying to figure out how to call a method on that hosted service from a test method.  I set the host variable as a property on the test class so I can reference host as needed from my test method.  However, the host property does not have dot notation to any of the methods associated with the service for which it was created.  Please advise.